# Make multisite non-existing subdomains go to homepage instead of Index of/ page

Tags: multisite, redirect, subdomains

I have a multisite with subdomains working in cPanel but non existing subdomains send users to Index of/ page, even though I have an index.php page.

How do I make it so only non-existing subdomains redirect people to my main domain.

For example:

```
mydomain.com > mydomain.com

existingsub.mydomain.com > existingsub.mydomain.com

nonexistingsub.mydomain.com > mydomain.com

765dast6dg.mydomain.com > mydomain.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the `NOBLOGREDIRECT` PHP constant within `wp-config.php`? That constant can be used to redirect users wherever you want when they visit a subdomain within multisite that doesn't exist.

Here's an example of that constant in use within `wp-config.php`:

```php
define( 'NOBLOGREDIRECT', 'https://example.com' );
```